# MongoDb getIndexes 'Collection' object is not callable

Tags: mongodb

I am trying use getIndexes() on a collection but getting error.
This is the simple code:

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client.new_db
exCollection=db.exCollection
exCollection.getIndexes()
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'getIndexes' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

I am using pymongo 3.7.
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I havent used pymongo, but it seems like getIndexes() is not present in pymongo. You need to use Collection.index_information as mentioned here http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.index_information.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. In this page "https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/", I could find how can I use getIndexes method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent used pymongo, but it seems like getIndexes() is not present in pymongo. You need to use Collection.index_information as mentioned [Click here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.index_information)

Comment: `collection.index_information()` is working in `pymongo` but the link is not working